# Google follow button change directions from ltr to rtl

Tags: localization, google-plus

I need to change directions for google follow button. On screen you can see that twitter (point 2) is changed when I select language, but google (point 1) don't do this.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: During last 2 months Google Plus is absolutely flooded by porn spam posts that use these or similar east asian languages. Looks like they outsource it to Russian coders...

Comment: So, what I need to do?